# Can line break character written inside the list affect it in anyway beside the layout?

Tags: python, list, selenium-webdriver

I was playing around with selenium and txt.readlines() when suddenly I noticed that there is a linebreak characters inside my list from reading a txt file. Here is an example

```
thislist =['https://www.microcenter.com/\n','https://www.something.com/']
```

Now ofcourse if I put thislist[0] in print then the linebreak character will disappear however it still exist inside the list if I print it out fully inside bracket. And before I get to do any .strip(\n) to get the linebreak out of the list, I noticed that Selenium still behave normally and go to `https://www.microcenter.com/` instead of `'https://www.microcenter.com/\n` which would return nothing like what I expected. Here is the code that I have for it

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
   url=thislist[0]
   driver.get(url)
```

(I'm sorry I type this in myself and I can't make it to have a linebreak characters ironically)

So the curiosity got me and I was wondering that could it be that selenium auto removing the linebreak characters or that it paste the content into chrome in someway that it would just throw the linebreak character out? And I also want to know why in order to counter whatever errors could occur too. Thank you

I've tried looking for various type of question on chrome:

-Do selenium auto remove \n characters

- Selenium Documentaion

-How selenium work
..... and many more but notthing seem to mention this.

Comment: Most methods of reading lines from a file will put a `\n` at the end of the line.  If you don't want that, strip it off.

Comment: Hi @JohnGordon, I  was about to do it actually. But before I got to do it I've noticed that the code just worked without any issue. Hence why I asked this question, Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing that all non-printing/control characters sent as arguments to the webdriver executable will be ignored.